# Azure Bash - Permission denied when running . <(sudo wget -q -O - https://aka.ms/microservices-data-aspnet-core-setup)

Tags: bash, azure, azureportal

I'm trying to setup my environment to learn azure from the Microsoft learning page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/microservices-data-aspnet-core/environment-setup

but when i run  `. <(sudo wget -q -O - https://aka.ms/microservices-data-aspnet-core-setup)` to pull the repo and run the services, i get the error below

```
~/clouddrive/aspnet-learn/modules/microservices-data-aspnet-core/setup ~/clouddrive/aspnet-learn
~/clouddrive/aspnet-learn

bash: /home/username/clouddrive/aspnet-learn/src/deploy/k8s/quickstart.sh: Permission denied
bash: /home/username/clouddrive/aspnet-learn/src/deploy/k8s/create-acr.sh: Permission denied
cat: /home/username/clouddrive/aspnet-learn/deployment-urls.txt: No such file or directory
```

this used to work until it stopped working and I'm not sure what caused it to break or how to fix it.

I've tried deleting the 'Storage account' and the resources, but doesn't seem to work. also, when i delete the storage account and create a new one then try again, it seems to have the old data stored and i need to run a remove, so somehow this data isnt really being deleted when i delete the 'Storage account'

```
Before running this script, please remove or rename the existing /home/username/clouddrive/aspnet-learn/ directory as follows:
Remove: rm -r /home/username/clouddrive/aspnet-learn/
```

[image]

any idea what is wrong here, or how i can actually reset this to work like a new storage?

Note: I saw some solutions which say to start with sudo, for elevated permission, but didnt manage to get this to work

Answer (score 0):

- I have done the repro by following  the given document
- Able to deploy a  modified version of the *eShopOnContainers*  [reference app](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eshoponcontainers)

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Again I executed the same command ,

```cs
 . <(wget -q -O - https://aka.ms/microservices-data-aspnet-core-setup)
```

got the same error which you have got

[image]

- ***If we try to run the deploy script without cleaning the already created resource/app,will get the above error.***
- If you want to re-run the setup script, run the below command first to clean the resource

```cs
cd ~ && \
 rm -rf ~/clouddrive/aspnet-learn && \
 az group delete --name eshop-learn-rg --yes
```

**OR**

```cs
Remove: rm -r /home/username/clouddrive/aspnet-learn/
Rename: mv /home/username/clouddrive/aspnet-learn/ ~/clouddrive/new-name-here/
```

***The above command  removes or renames  the existing /home/username/clouddrive/aspnet-learn/ directory***

- Now you can run the script again

Comment: thanks for looking into this soo indepth, unfortunately my issue isnt that the folder is present (ive already tried the removing it, as mentioned in the question)
my problem is that when i run it after removing the existing folder, i get this error (next comment) which looks like some permission error

Comment: `bash: /home/username/clouddrive/aspnet-learn/src/deploy/k8s/quickstart.sh: Permission denied`
`bash: /home/username/clouddrive/aspnet-learn/src/deploy/k8s/create-acr.sh: Permission denied`
`cat: /home/username/clouddrive/aspnet-learn/deployment-urls.txt: No such file or directory`